# Ratio of perimeter of two triangles with common side

Tags: geometry, triangles

Consider the triangle $ABC$ shown in the following figure where $BC = 12cm, DB = 9cm $ & $CD= 6cm$ and angle $BCD$ = angle $BAC$. What is the ratio of the perimeter of the triangle ADC to that of the triangle BDC?

[image]

I have figured out the side $AC$ length which is $8cm$ using the Sine Rule in triangles $BDC$ and $ABC$ but after that I am not able to proceed in the question. I am trying to find out somehow the value of $AD$ or $AB$ but unfortunately I am not able to do so.

Please help me with this question. I know I must be missing something very small in this.

Thanks in advance !

UPDATE : Just now I also got to realize that...now it can be solved using the similar triangles approach...anyway I was thinking if we can get to the value of $AB$ or $AD$ by using any another approach like Sine Rule or any other theorem. Just asking for if in any case that comes into handy for solving some another question.

Comment: ABC and BCD are similar, which leads to AC=8 and AB =16

Comment: @Quanto : yeah..just now I also got to realize that...now it can be solved using the similar triangles approach...anyway I was thinking if we can get to the value of $AB$ or $AD$ by using any another approach like Sine Rule or any other theorem. Just asking for if in any case that comes into handy for solving some another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta BDC \sim \Delta BCA$ because $m( \angle BCD) = m( \angle BAC)$ and $\angle B$ is a common angle.
And we can continue from here, to end up with $AB = 16, AC=8$, which means that our answer is $\frac {7+8+6}{6+9+12}=\frac {7}{9}$

---

You can say the same thing using trignometric functions as:
$$\frac {6}{\sin(\angle B)}= \frac {9}{\sin(\angle BCD)} \\ \frac {AC}{\sin(\angle B)}= \frac{12}{\sin(\angle A)} \\ m(\angle A) = m (\angle BCD), m(\angle C) = m(\angle BDC) \\ \implies \frac {6}{AC}=\frac{9}{12}=\frac{12}{AB}$$
And from that we can calculate the missing values: $AC = 8, AB = 16$. And then we can find the answer: $\frac {7+8+6}{6+9+12}=\frac {7}{9}$.

Comment: Please see the update in my question.